# js onClick="window.open Parent loading base url

Tags: javascript, popup

I have what I hope is a simple js problem. I'm working on a art project. In the site I have an image on a page. I've wrapped the image tag with a link and a bit of inline js. I have the behavior I'd like: on.click opens a new window with the correct link just fine. However the parent page is loading the base url for the website and I'd rather it did nothing. Anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this? It seems to be just fine in FF but webkit isn't playing nice. You can see a quick demo here: http://jacksontuckerlynch.com/webcam-24

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.something.com/some-page?m=1','mywindow','width=710,height=700,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=no')"><img class="responsecontainer" src="http://somewebsite.net/image.jpg" width="260" height="180" /><a/>
```

Many thanks for your experience.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

There are lots of ways to disable the href attribute but this one is probably the most simple. I think you can even remove the href attribute but then you have to add some css to style the mouse to point on hover

Comment: That did the trick. 
Thanks of your help. How simple it was!

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return false;` at the end of your javascript like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.something.com/some-page?m=1','mywindow','width=710,height=700,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=no'); return false;"><img class="responsecontainer" src="http://somewebsite.net/image.jpg" width="260" height="180" /><a/>
```